# Rails .include? returns true when it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm testing my ActiveRecord models in RSpec and I'm trying to speed up my tests by just instantiating models instead of creating a FactoryGirl model, but `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy.include?` is returning `true` when I expect `false`.

The code I'm testing is this method in the Schedule model, which is passed an argument of an instance of the Location model...

```
def available_at_location(location)
  locations.include?(location)
end
```

And the test is...

```
before do
  subject.locations = [location_b]
end

it 'returns false' do
  result = subject.available_at_location(location_a)

  expect(result).to be(false)
end
```

When I create `location_a` and `location_b` with FactoryGirl the test passes and `include?` returns `false`, but when I instantiate `location_a` and `location_b` with this code, the test fails and include? returns `true`.

```
let(:location_a) { Location.new(name: 'London') }
let(:location_b) { Location.new(name: 'York') }
```

Printing `locations` shows that it is a CollectionProxy containing `location_b`, and printing the `location` argument shows that it is `location_a`, both with the correct properties. And, the `include?` returns `true` whether the `location` argument is passed or not.

EDIT: Some additional code.

This is the code to define the subject...

```
subject { described_class.new(locations: [location_a]) }
```

And this is the code for the FactoryGirl Location factory...

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :location do
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    address { Faker::Address.street_address }
    city { Faker::Address.city }
    zipcode { Faker::Address.zip_code }
    landline { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
    association :organization
  end
end
```

N.B. I've tried providing an Organization to the constructor (`Location.new(name: 'London', organization: Organization.new)`) but it doesn't change the output.

Comment: please, provide your subject factory code.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you meant the definition of the subject (I've not used FG to create the subject at any point) or the FactoryGirl for the Location, but I provided both in an edit to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked out the solution. I'll document this here in case anyone else has a similar issue. These lines are the problem...

```
subject { described_class.new(locations: [location_a]) }

before do
  subject.locations = [location_b]
end
```

When using instances of your model instead of full blown DB models made by FactoryGirl, ActiveRecord doesn't update changes to the items in CollectionProxies. As far as it's concerned `locations` is always `[location_a]` even if you change the items to `[location_b]`.

The solution is to only assign the properties once. I.e.

```
subject { described_class.new(locations: []) }

before do
  subject.locations = [location_b]
end
```

Set the location in each context's before block to the required location.

I'm sure this is something to do with references to the Collection/CollectionProxy, but it's beyond me.

Answer (score 4):

`CollectionProxy` compares models by their `id`s, since both records are new and have `id == nil` - `include?` returns `true`.

To have your test working you have to save models to db (use `create!` and so on)

Comment: I've tried supplying an `id` in the Location constructor and that didn't help. Does it only work when the models are saved to the DB?

Comment: It's can be frustrating to write AR model tests that only use instantiated but not saved objects. Quite often you run into situations where you need a saved object (with an ID), that you didn't expect. You might try extracting methods from the model and putting them into other classes, where you can test them without interacting with the DB.

Comment: To add a quick note. After some digging in the code, for in-memory records, CollectionProxy does object equivalence not ID comparison.